# IProgressMonitor progress needs to be start from 1,2...100

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have to implement eclipse plugin import wizard and needs to show the progress of the process from 1 to 100. In the import process i have four subtask so i have used IProgressmonitor and subprogressmonitor concept. To show the progress i have set unit of works in worked(unitofworks) method so it's showing only unitofworks in the progress not incrementing like 1,2,3...100.

And one more issue i am facing like how to handle cancel option because i have many subtask so i don't know where to use cancelled method.

Please provide simple code snippet to show the progress from 1 to 100 with cancel option.

Answer (score 0):

No. You should focus on your units of "work" and let the (sub)progress monitors handle the math. Go read https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Progress-Monitors/article.html .